# Firebase authentication signs out previously authenticated users causing permission denied errors for them

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

1) User X visits my webpage, and X is correctly authenticated and able to write to my firebase database via the web browser.

2) User Y then visits my webpage, and Y is authenticated and able to write to my firebase database via the web browser. **However**, after User Y is authenticated, User X starts getting "Permission Denied" console log messages within the browser and is no longer able to write to firebase.

### Why is X losing authentication privileges when Y is authenticated?

Here is the Node.js server code:

```
token = Fb.auth().createCustomToken(uid, params);
...
response.render('pages/xyz', {settings:settings, token:token, ...});
```

Here is the html/js delivered by Node.js to the browser:

```
firebase.initializeApp(<%- JSON.stringify(settings);%>);
db = firebase.database();
function initApp() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });
}

$('document').ready(function(){
    initApp();
    firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken('<%=token%>').catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate multiple users within the same tab of a browser? That won't work. Firebase Authentication has at most a single signed-in user per app.

Comment: Ah yes. I was testing it by opening two different browser tabs (for two different users) within the same browser.

Comment: That won't work. If you want to test locally, try different browsers, or a regular tab + an incognito window.

Comment: K thanks. If you to write this as the answer below I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Only a single person can be authenticated in an app at one time.

If you open multiple tabs in the same browser window, they will very likely end up as a single user.

To have multiple users on a single machine, either use a different, secondary browser or open an incognito window.